# Computer clock keeps changing time but date seems correct

Tags: windows-7, laptop, bios, battery

First I thought it is a Cmos battery problem. Maybe it still is. I thought it was because the computer is running win 7 so it is old. Before when I turned on the computer it would change the time. Now I noticed even when its plugged into the wall it changes the time. Even after I correct it and computer is still on. Date seems correct.

If it was a Cmos battery issue the date and time should stay same as long as the laptop is on and windows 7 is active right? Or will a bad cmos battery change date and time while then computer is on and plugged in. It is a laptop and I did take the battery out so it runs on power only.

Comment: Be specific: by how much? If it's in increments of 1 hour or 1/2 hr (Russia), then it's the time zone or DST issue.

Comment: Seems random but that is a good point will turn it on and see. I think this started after day light savings time.

Comment: Put a new cmos battery in it, they are cheap.

Comment: So I noted the times and dates.                             Correct time 6:37 pm 03/17

Computer time 10:57 am 03/17                                            

Was not online.                                                                        Correct time 12:16 pm 03/20/2020                   Laptop time 6:41 pm 03/17/2020 computer was not online. Is this a cmos issue or something else?

Comment: Current time 1:39 pm 03/20/2020. Computer time 12:48 pm 03/20/2020. This time the computer was on. The date stayed current but time changed.